# проблема с созданием адаптивного блока

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, при создание блока с картинка возникла проблема что при сужение все валиться куда попало, хотелось бы чтоб переносилось по 2 блока. И нижние картинки были по центру, с помощью бутстрап

```
<div class="preim">
<div><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div></div>
<div class="preim">
    <div><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
    <div><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
</div> </div>
</div>
```

ссылка на страницу http://advancedfood.ru/o_kompanii

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вам это? У Вас бутстрап подключен же.

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-3">...</div>
    <div class = "col-md-4">...</div>
    ....
 </div>
```

Всё давно придумано. 
С таким вариантом ничего никуда не поползет. Плюсом, можно настроить отобрадение на разных устройствах как нужно.

Ознакомиться с сеткой Bootstrap можно тут: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

На русском: http://bootstrap-3.ru

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не нужна поддержка IE9 (что вряд ли), то используйте для этого flexbox http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/

Сейчас же все валится туда, куда должно :-)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю воспользоваться возможностями уже подключенного к сайту бутстрапу. Попробуй такую структуру.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><img src="" alt=""><p></p></div>
</div>
```

Класс *text-center* - в бутстрапе выравнивает содержимое блока по центру.

*"row"* обозначает ряд, а *col-md-1* - ячейки (столбец).

Бутстрап сам решает, какое кол-во картинок ему переносить в зависимости от сужения и размера картинки. Разные телефоны имеют разные расширения, если на одном телефоне оптимально - 2, то на другом это одна картинка в "ряду" или три. Предлагаю не переживать по этому поводу. Если две штуки на ряд - это категорично, напиши. Подправим код

Comment: Никто бутстрап не просил.

Comment: Qwertiy, я код сайта посмотрел. Бутстрап уже подключен.

Comment: да, по возможности бутстрап, спасибо

Comment: но не сработало, теперь все в один столбец

Comment: цифры должны быть одинаковые.